# What is the section before the commas called at the start of a sentence after words such as "well" or "however"

Tags: terminology

For example:

> Well, that was his answer anyways.

Or

> However, the answer was wrong.

Comment: They're still called "commas"?

Comment: Im not talking specifically about just the comma; I mean the use case. For example a word with an apostrophe showing possession is called a possessive while one showing combined words such as they're are called contractions. This has no word specifically to talk about the word(s) before a sentence that requires a comma after?

Comment: Well technically it is a sentence that opens with a conjunctive adverb. No sure if it has a specialize name.

Comment: @Oscar: That depends on the word themselves, they don't belong all to the same category. Usually they are adverbs, though, but not necessarily.

Comment: @Oscar Godson Oh, you mean the whole piece, like a "clause" or something.  I'm sure someone here knows that.

Comment: Wait, why did you change the question totally? First you ask about the comma, now you ask about the section. So my answer seems off-topic... :| I'll "delete" it temporary, but before you ask, be sure of what you ask.

Comment: @Alenanno it made sense in my head, but then after you answered I realized it'll confuse people. To me the comma marks a "section", but I realize a comma can also be seen as just a single character. So I made it more clear

Comment: @Oscar: Ok I see...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call this a *sentence adverb*:

NOAD definition:

> **sentence adverb**
> *noun* Grammar
> an adverb or adverbial phrase that expresses a writer's or speaker's attitude to the content of the sentence in which it occurs (such as *frankly*, *obviously*), or places the sentence in a particular context (such as *technically*, *politically*).

[Usage note](http://rammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/sentadvqa.htm) from About.com:

> Unlike an ordinary adverb — which is conventionally defined as a word that modifies a verb, adjective, or other adverb — a sentence adverb modifies a sentence as a whole or a clause within a sentence.
>
> Dozens of words can be used as sentence adverbs, among them *actually, apparently, basically, briefly, certainly, clearly, conceivably, confidentially, curiously, evidently, fortunately, hopefully, however, ideally, incidentally, indeed, interestingly, ironically, naturally, predictably, presumably, regrettably, seriously, strangely, surprisingly, thankfully, theoretically, therefore, truthfully, ultimately*, and *wisely*.

*Well* may well be used as a sentence adverb as well. Or it could be construed as an exclamation.