# Can "I wonder" be put at the end of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-order

Usually sentences with "I wonder" are of the following form:

> I wonder why ***_*__*_*___**.

But what about this?

> Why is it that ***_*__*_*__*_*** I
>   wonder.

It seems relatively unnatural. Why is that? Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: I think you'd be fine with "Why is it that {etc}, I wonder." Note the comma, which makes the "I wonder" more like an afterthought.

Comment: @Kit: Oh so I was right about the comma :D I usually do it by heart, so I wasn't sure there was a rule, but I was pretty much sure of it...

Comment: Lyrics from "The Sound of Music": *What would this day be like, I wonder. What will my future be, I wonder.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can, there's no rule against it. Usually it's preceded by a comma:

> Why is it that [...], I wonder.

or like this example taken from [here](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/wonder_1), after direct speech:

> ‘*What should I do now?*’ she wondered.

Comment: I'd never thought of this device in terms of speech tags before!  Thank you.

Comment: The pattern "<question>, I wonder" is very natural (and so must be grammatical?), whatever the punctuation should be.

Comment: Can you give an example where a comma isn't needed?

Comment: In order to be sure, I searched a bit, but I doubt a sentence ending with "I wonder" will be missing a comma, since the sentence will have a weird grammatical and syntax structure, like "Will she come here I wonder." The only usage I found where it didn't have a comma, is the second example I quoted. :)

Answer (score 4):

This kind of sentence-ending question may also be a rhetorical figure known as [aporia](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aporia) (second entry on the linked page):

> **aporia** [əˈpɔːrɪə]
>   *n*
>   1. ... *Rhetoric* a doubt, real or professed, about what to do or say

It can also be construed as a [sentence adverb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28428/what-is-the-section-before-the-commas-called-at-the-start-of-a-sentence-after-wor/28441#28441) (also "sentential adverb") which is "an adverb or adverbial phrase that expresses a writer's or speaker's attitude to the content of the sentence in which it occurs."