# When to write the word “parenthetically”

Tags: phrases, parentheses

I understand that if you're speaking a phrase in which you would write parentheses, you can say the word *parenthetically*. But when should you *write* the word *parenthetically*?

I came across this sentence, starting off a paragraph in a scientific article:

> Parenthetically, we note that subjects in all experimental conditions were unbiased …

This struck me as odd. If they're speaking parenthetically, shouldn't it be in parentheses? On the one hand, from a descriptive point of view, the usage of the word was not ambiguous – I know exactly what the author is trying to connote by using it. But from a prescriptive point of view, would this be considered proper grammar?

Comment: In the paper, if that sentence were enclosed in parentheses, the entire paragraph would need to be there too. Just saying *parenthetically* is the least awkward option. And possibly it implies a bit of "they make us say this, you know."

Comment: *Parenthetically* here functions as a **sentence adverb**. See [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/28441/2303) for more information.

Comment: You would write it here: ["Parenthetically"](http://magnificentnose.com/2011/05/04/parenthetically/). (Sorry, couldn't resist!)

Comment: parenthetically - to introduce a sentence or remark which is explanatory

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The use of *parenthetically* is not limited to the literal meaning of appearing between brackets.  It can, as in your example, mean simply ‘as an aside’.

Comment: Ah, so they were writing *metaphorically* parenthetically.

Comment: @TomAnderson: Quite so.

Comment: I think you mean "exactally".

Comment: @TomAnderson, To be fair, that's the [original meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parenthesis#Noun) of parenthesis. The `(` and `)` are called brackets. They're so often used to signify *parenthesis* to the extent that now people even call them that.

Answer (score 7):

Don't confuse the punctuation marks routinely used to convey an idea with the idea itself, even when the punctuation marks have a same or similar name as the idea. It's quite reasonable to say, "Charles QUESTIONED the speaker's statement" without using a question mark (because I do not actually quote the question). "When I asked my children where they wanted to go for vacation, they EXCLAIMED that they wanted to go to Disney World." Etc.

Comment: [Exactly](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56036/when-to-write-the-word-parenthetically#comment539838_56041).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to its prescriptive purpose, *parenthetically* may also be used in a more abstract sense, by definition:

> Set off within or as if within parentheses; qualifying or explanatory

It's worth noting that there is a difference between a *parenthesis* and *parentheses*, the former being a rhetoric device and the latter being punctuation. (Parentheses usually - but not always - enclose a parenthetical remark.)

Comment: Isn't *parentheses* just the plural of *parenthesis*. Since they're usually used in pairs in punctuation, you use the plural word for punctuation (although you would say "you're missing a right parenthesis here").

Comment: @Peter Indeed. Both the punctuation mark and the rhetorical device share the same singular and plural forms, which adds to the confusion. See [Pathenthesis (rhetoric)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_(rhetoric)) for further details.

Comment: @HaL, Your explanation in the answer is bad. Readers would think that there's a difference in spelling between the two concepts, but no, the two concepts are spelled [identically](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56036/when-to-write-the-word-parenthetically#comment539838_56041).

Comment: @Pacerier: Feel free to edit this answer if it can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good word to use in speech, when you can't show actual parentheses. In the context you give, it's probably just a stylistic choice, if an ill-advised one. Parenthetically, I note that scientific papers are not always models of perfect grammar and word choice.

Comment: Your last sentence eloquently refutes your second sentence. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The word "**parenthesis**" is a Greek word, as every sophisticated word is... so, parenthesis (παρένθεσις) is exactly this: (  ). This is a parenthesis. When we say *parenthetically*, we mean that we add an idea to our text which it may seem unnecessary but we judge that it would enforce our point we wish to make.

Answer (score 0):

I am mainly copying the entry because of the example below. Synonyms might help too

> [parenthetically](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parenthetically)
>
> adverb
>
> **incidentally, by the way, in passing, by way of explanation, by the bye**
>
> *This brings us, parenthetically, to another question.*

Collins Thesaurus of the English Language – Complete and Unabridged 2nd Edition. 2002 © HarperCollins Publishers 1995, 2002

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the use of the word parenthetically is used as a tangential idea separate from, but related, to the subject of the discourse.